# Android app crash when FTP object is created

Tags: android, ftp

I'm trying to create an FTP connection in my android app, and when I instantiate the object for the class `FTPCLient`, my app crashes.
I downloaded `org.apache.commons.net.ftp` from the Apache web site.
I found out that my issue happens when I use this

`FTPClient myFTP = new FTPClient()`;

Comment: Make sure u add this permission in manifest file **android.permission.INTERNET** . Post the code and error.

Comment: With the crash log and relevant code, answers are likely to be only speculation.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that it didnt work because i had to attach the external lib in other to export it with the apk.